# Matsusaka's big theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Siu proved that given an ample line bundle $\mathcal L$, a numerically effective line bundle $\mathcal M$, there exists an integer $l_0$ which depends only on $(\mathcal L^n)$, $(\omega_X \cdot \mathcal L^{n - 1})$ and $(\mathcal M \cdot \mathcal L^{n - 1})$ such that $\mathcal L ^{\otimes l} \otimes \mathcal M^{\otimes -1}$ is very ample for every $l \ge l_0$. My question is that is this true for any line bundle $\mathcal M$, not necessarily numerically effective? If not, is there a counterexample?

Comment: Unless I am missing something… the line bundles on P1xP1 are just O(a,b). O(a,b) is ample <=> it is very ample <=> a>0 and  b>0. Consider L=O(1,1) and M=O(k,-k). Then L.M=0 for any k, so all the intersections are independent of k. But there is no power of L which satisfies the very ampleness for all k.